# Facing issue of build taking longer time while copying and publishing npm and node.js in Azure Devops Pipeline

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-devops, cicd, npm-package

I'm new to next.js build pipeline setup. Able to publish the artifacts but copying files and publishing the artifacts is taking loner time i.e., 30+ minutes. How can I reduce the build time. Included cache in the build but it did not work

Tried adding cache task

Comment: Please share your pipeline definition(eg: yaml) and screenshots related, so we can know more clear on the task details which take longer time(30mins), and what's the cache task behavior. Is it `cache hit` and restored the files correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below yaml pipeline to build and publish your NextJs  node app artifact and deploy it in Azure Web app:-

**My yaml code:-**

```yaml
trigger:
- main

variables:

  
  azureSubscription: 'xxxxxxe94d93'

  
  webAppName: 'valleynextjsapp'

  
  environmentName: 'valleynextjsapp'

  
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - task: NodeTool@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '18.x'
      displayName: 'Install Node.js'

    - script: |
        npm install
        npm run build --if-present
        npm run test --if-present
      displayName: 'npm install, build and test'

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: $(environmentName)
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: AzureWebApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy: siliconwebapp655'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: 'xxxx subscription (0151xxxxx)'
              appType: 'webAppLinux'
              appName: 'siliconwebapp89'
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
              runtimeStack: 'NODE|18-lts'
              startUpCommand: 'next start'
```

***Output:-***

[image]

You can also try below yaml code to caching your npm build :-

```yaml
trigger:
- main

variables:
  azureSubscription: '5b7exxxxxe94d93'
  webAppName: 'valleynextjsapp'
  environmentName: 'valleynextjsapp'
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - task: NodeTool@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '18.x'
      displayName: 'Install Node.js'

    - task: Cache@2
      inputs:
        key: 'npm | "$(Agent.OS)" | package-lock.json'
        restoreKeys: |
           npm | "$(Agent.OS)"
        path: $(npm_config_cache)
      displayName: 'Cache npm'

    - script: |
        npm ci
        npm run build --if-present
        npm run test --if-present
      displayName: 'npm install, build and test'

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: $(environmentName)
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: AzureWebApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy: $(webAppName)'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
              appType: webAppLinux
              appName: $(webAppName)
              runtimeStack: 'NODE|18.10'
              package: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip
              startUpCommand: 'next start'
```

**`$(npm_config_cache)` is the location of your npm cache:-**

```yaml
variables:  npm_config_cache:  $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.npm_cache
```

**Output:-**

[image]